# Mysql: Why is WHERE IN much faster than JOIN in this case?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query with a long list (> 2000 ids) in a WHERE IN clause in mysql (InnoDB):

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE user_id IN ('list of >2000 ids')
```

I tried to optimize this by using an INNER JOIN instead of the wherein like this (both ids and the user_id use an index):

```
SELECT table.id 
FROM table 
INNER JOIN users ON table.user_id = users.id WHERE users.type = 1
```

Surprisingly, however, the first query is much faster (by the factor 5 to 6). Why is this the case? Could it be that the second query outperforms the first one, when the number of ids in the where in clause becomes much larger?

Comment: Run `explain select ...` to get the plan of the queries.

Comment: firstly, maybe users.type has no index? Secondly, join is expensive thing, because it needs to scan all rows and join tables and then perform lookup. In first query you immediately do lookup

Comment: Also note that how much you fit in to the IN clause depends on max_allowed_packet

Comment: Both are sub par (at least, was, depending on the mysql version you are using). Try SELECT table.id FROM table WHERE (SELECT type FROM users WHERE table.user_id = users.id) = 1 to see if it is any better.

Comment: @Andrew if the fields participating in the join are appropriately indexed, then there is no need to scan an entire table just because of the join.

Comment: Also by a factor of 5 to 6? what exactly does that mean 10 ms vs 50ms?

Comment: @Shadow well if results make up major part of the table, even using index, then you are scanning (joining?) most of the table rows and this is additional operation which costs. With small tables that's fine but if you have lots of rows, it may be costly.

Comment: @Andrew trust me, there is a huge difference in performance of joins using indexes and using full table scan.

Comment: @Shadow no question about it, if you have indexes on joined fields - it will be much faster. But sometimes even using them, it is still too slow. Directly taking what you need from the table (and joining results in higher level language), with big tables, sometimes can be 100x faster than using joins with indexes

Comment: @Andrew this is fine, but then pls do not provide some incorrect explanation in the first instance about joins being slow because they need to scan all rows next time.

Comment: What version are you using?  5.6 made some improvements in one of these; 5.7 made more improvements.

Comment: How long did it take to get the 2000+ ids?

Comment: Do you have `INDEX(type, id)`?

Comment: @Shadow joins are slow, because they need to find those rows and this is costly. If you don't have lots of rows and thus operation takes short time, that doesn't make join slow. You just don't use lots of 'joins'. And when you go into larger quantities they do become slow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Ans to your Question but you may use as alternative to your first query, You can better increase performance by replacing `IN` Clause with `EXISTS` since `EXISTS` performance better than `IN` ref : <kbd>[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/05/sql-server-convert-in-to-exists-performance-talk/)</kbd>

```
SELECT id 
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USERS WHERE t.user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: This discussion is about mysql and not sql server (complaint about your reference)

Comment: Well, but mechanism behind is same

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfair comparison between the 2 queries.

- In the 1st query you provide a list of constants as a search criteria, therefore MySQL has to open and search only table and / or 1 index file.
- In the 2nd query you instruct MySQL to obtain the list dynamically from another table and join that list back to the main table. It is also not clear, if indexes were used to create a join or a full table scan was needed.

To have a fair comparison, time the query that you used to obtain the list in the 1st query along with the query itself. Or try

```
SELECT table.id FROM table WHERE user_id IN (SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.type = 1)
```

The above fetches the list of ids dynamically in a subquery.